# Help me understand this sample code for new ERC20 token

Tags: ether, erc-20

This is my first question here so please bear with me.

I have deployed my first token on test network.
I was reading about how to improve Token contracts and stumbled upon this sample file.

This file looked very neatly written but at the same time raised some questions.

https://github.com/bitfwdcommunity/Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial%201/tutorial1_contract.sol

Can someone please **confirm me** following: -

1)
These are functions to safely perform math operations, Right?

```
contract SafeMath { }
```

2)
What is the use of `ApproveAndCallFallBack` ?

```
contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
}
```

3)
What is this contract `Owned` ?
I dont get it.

```
contract Owned {
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Yes its used to prevent integers from overflowing or other invalid inputs that could cheat system or cause errors.

2.) **ApproveAndCallFallBack** is an interface that is used to make calls to other contract that have implementation of **receiveApproval** function.

As you can see here:

```
function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
}
```

Its used to make call to external contract where spender is address of that contract.

3.) Owned is used for functions that have restricted access, every function that have modifier **onlyOwner** for example here its used for **transferAnyERC20Token** function, can be accessed only by address that is stored in owner variable. Which is at start address that deployed contract, and later can be changed from that address using functions **transferOwnership** and **acceptOwnership** from new owner address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. So if I understand correctly, constructor `function Owned() public` is called ONCE when contract is deployed. So it saves address of the deployer as `owner` ?

Comment: Also they have address hard coded in constructor `function FucksToken() public` and once coins are created they are moved to the **hard coded** address using this command `Transfer(address(0), 0x5A86f0cafD4ef3ba4f0344C138afcC84bd1ED222, _totalSupply);`

Comment: In first case yes, its called once and saves deployer address as owner. But in FucksToken() constructor yes there are hard coded address, but command `Transfer(address(0), 0x5A86f0cafD4ef3ba4f0344C138afcC84bd1ED222, _totalSupply);` is used to fire Event that is described in ERC20Interface, actual code that allocates tokens is this command: `balances[0x5A86f0cafD4ef3ba4f0344C138afcC84bd1ED222] = _totalSupply;`